# Load compressed data from Amazon S3 to Postgres using datastage

Tags: amazon-s3, etl, datastage, ibm-infosphere

I am trying to load data which is stored in .gz format in S3 to PostgreSQL server using Datastage. I am using the ODBC connector on the target (database) side. I am able to load uncompressed data from S3 to PostgreSQL but no luck with compressed data so far. I have tried the `Expand Stage` but it's not helping or I am not doing the right thing. Without the "Expand" the data is coming but it is trying to read the compressed data, while doing so it fails and throws an error:

```
Amazon_S3_0,1: com.ascential.e2.common.CC_Exception: Failed to initialize the parser: The row delimiter was not found within the first 132 bytes of the file. Ensure that the Row delimiter property matches the row delimiter of the file.
at com.ibm.iis.cc.cloud.CloudLogger.createCCException (CloudLogger.java: 196)
at com.ibm.iis.cc.cloud.CloudStage.processReadAndParse (CloudStage.java: 1591)
at com.ibm.iis.cc.cloud.CloudStage.process (CloudStage.java: 680)
at com.ibm.is.cc.javastage.connector.CC_JavaAdapter.run (CC_JavaAdapter.java: 443)


Amazon_S3_0,1: Failed to initialize the parser: The row delimiter was not found within the first 132 bytes of the file. Ensure that the Row delimiter property matches the row delimiter of the file. (com.ibm.iis.cc.cloud.CloudLogger::createCCException, file CloudLogger.java, line 196)
```

If someone has come across this, please share your valuable inputs.